# Querying JSON with SelectTokens in c#

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net, querying

I need some help with parsing a JObject. The following json is the result of this line of code in c# :

```
var o = JObject.Parse(data);

o   {{
  "firstdata": {
    "count": 17,
    "firstOccurrence": 1493663381786,
    "lastOccurrence": 1493681141398
  },
  "views": {
    "count": 17,
    "firstOccurrence": 1493663381787,
    "lastOccurrence": 1493681141398
  },
  "session": {
    "count": 57,
    "firstOccurrence": 1493663381787,
    "lastOccurrence": 1493681159212
  },
  "test": {
    "count": 17,
    "firstOccurrence": 1493663381788,
    "lastOccurrence": 1493681141399
  },
  "browser": {
    "count": 17,
    "firstOccurrence": 1493663381788,
    "lastOccurrence": 1493681141399
  },
  "click": {
    "count": 18,
    "firstOccurrence": 1493663381805,
    "lastOccurrence": 1493681141410
  },
  "click.Default": {
    "count": 18,
    "firstOccurrence": 1493663381805,
    "lastOccurrence": 1493681141410
  },
  "click.6": {
    "count": 18,
    "firstOccurrence": 1493663381805,
    "lastOccurrence": 1493681141410
  },
  "generic_Click.mail": {
    "count": 4,
    "firstOccurrence": 1493663488302,
    "lastOccurrence": 1493675499011
  },
  "generic_Click.calander": {
    "count": 3,
    "firstOccurrence": 1493663649203,
    "lastOccurrence": 1493675501110
  },
  "generic_Click.tweet": {
    "count": 2,
    "firstOccurrence": 1493663657444,
    "lastOccurrence": 1493675577793
  },
  "generic_Click.facebook": {
    "count": 3,
    "firstOccurrence": 1493663840925,
    "lastOccurrence": 1493677734366
  }
}}
```

What I need is to look for all elements in this json object that starts with "generic_click" and store their corresponding "count" values. I tried to look for one of them using this line of code, which returns null.

```
var test = o.SelectToken("generic_Click.facebook");
```

My guess is that the dot in "generic_Click.facebook" is causing the SelectToken considering this as a path, rather than a name to look for.

Can anybody help me with this please? I am trying to find a way to return "count" for all elements in this json objects that starts with "generic_Click."

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a LINQ query to gather the item names and counts into a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = JObject.Parse(data).Properties()
    .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("generic_Click"))
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => (int)p.Value["count"]);

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Oq4J4

Comment: Thank you so much Brian, this worked perfectly :). Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

To select a single element path with a period in the key just switch you selection process from

```
 o.SelectToken("generic_Click.facebook")
```

to

```
 o["generic_Click.facebook"]
```

to select many elements that contain you keyword **generic_Click** you can use linq as follows

```
var o = JObject.Parse(data);

var genericClick = o.AsJEnumerable().Where(x=>x.Path.Contains("generic_Click"));
```

and then you can loop through them as such

```
foreach (var token in genericClick)
{
   Console.Write(token.First()["count"]);
}
```

and get your **count** element.

I hope this helps.